# Objective-c SpriteKit CGRectMake left border

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to draw vertical line on the left border of screen, but line is't showed. What is wrong?

```
CGRect leftRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, self.size.height);
SKShapeNode *leftBorder = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRect:leftRect];
leftBorder.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
leftBorder.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
leftBorder.name = @"leftBorder";
leftBorder.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:leftBorder.frame];
leftBorder.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
[self addChild:leftBorder];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set size gameScene ,when u init it.

```
_gameScene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];

// Here
_gameScene.size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

_gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill; 

[skView presentScene:_gameScene];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode node];
CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 100.0, 100.0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 50.0, 50.0);
yourline.path = pathToDraw;
[yourline setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self addChild:yourline];
```

If it's not working, than it can be self. Be sure, that self is instance of SKScene.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but still nothing on emulator's screen

Comment: please give full code of class: how do you initialize this class, what's subclass of e.t.c.